# Nested perl arrays and hashes and references

Tags: perl

I have tried various combinations of @%$s but I cannot get this to work.  The full expression works, but how do I split it up into variables?

```
print "BIGexp ", $tables{"grp"}[1]{_name}, "\n"; # OK, prints part
my @cols = $tables{"grp"};
print "COLS ", @cols, "\n"; # prints array
my %col = %cols[1]; 
print "COLvar ", %col, " ", "\n"; #prints 1 ?
print "COLexp ", $cols[1]{_name}, "\n";  ######## Fails, uninitialized.
```

I want to represent database schemas.  So a map of tables, each containing an array of columns, each of which is a map.  Here is the full fragment.

```
my %tables=();

my $columns; # array

sub addTable {
  my @cols = ();
  $tables{$_[0]} = \@cols;
  $columns = \@cols;
}

sub addColumn {
    my %col  = (_name => $_[0],  _typ => $_[1]);
    push(@$columns , \%col);
}

addTable("grp");
addColumn("id", "serial");
addColumn("part", "integer");

addTable("tab2");
addColumn("foo2", "varchar");
addColumn("bar2", "integer");

print "BIGexp ", $tables{"grp"}[1]{_name}, "\n"; # OK, prints part
my @cols = $tables{"grp"};
print "COLS ", @cols, "\n"; # prints array
my %col = %cols[1]; 
print "COLvar ", %col, " ", "\n"; #prints 1 ?
print "COLexp ", $cols[1]{_name}, "\n";  ######## Fails, uninitialized.
```

I am new to Perl and have yet to become "Perl minded" :(.  Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Quick (but essential) reading to get you started with references: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut

Comment: *"my %col = %cols[1];"* : Try `my %col = %{$cols->[1]}`

Comment: "I have tried various combinations of @%$s" My favorite thing about this question is that it looks like you're censoring a swear but you're just accurately describing Perl syntax.

Comment: @Data yes, that reference is very good and got me the answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the posts, but none of them solved the actual problem.  The solution is

```
print "BIGexp ", $tables{"grp"}[1]{_name}, "\n"; # OK, part
my $cols = $tables{"grp"};  # ref array
my $col = ${$cols}[1];  # ref hash
my %colh = %{$col}; # hash
print "COLvar ", $colh{_name}, " ", "\n"; # bingo
print "COLvar2 ", ${$col}{_name}, " ", "\n"; # bingo
print "COL-> ", $col->{_name}, " ", "\n"; # bingo
```

The trick is taking care of the difference between a ref array and an array etc.  {$x} is the dereference operator.

I still do not really understand what "%" etc. really does though.  I suspect it is best to only ever use references and avoid % and @ entirely.

This link was very helpful
https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut

Comment: Before you proceed with that view, please check another section of the Perl docs as well, namely the one about Perl variables: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the module `use Data::Dumper;` in order to print your data structures.

```
print "BIGexp ", $tables{"grp"}[1]{_name}, "\n"; # OK, prints part
my @cols = $tables{"grp"};
print "COLS ", @cols, "\n"; # prints array
my %col = %cols[1]; 
print "COLvar ", Dumper(\%col), " ", "\n"; #prints 1 ?
print "COLexp ", Dumper(\@cols), "\n";  ######## Fails, uninitialized.

print "COLexp ", Dumper($cols[0][1]{_name}), "\n";
```

And the output is like:

```
   BIGexp part
COLS ARRAY(0x800e5f480)
COLvar $VAR1 = {
          '1' => undef
        };
 
COLexp $VAR1 = [
          [
            {
              '_typ' => 'serial',
              '_name' => 'id'
            },
            {
              '_name' => 'part',
              '_typ' => 'integer'
            }
          ]
        ];

COLexp $VAR1 = 'part';
```

As you can see, you actually have a nested array. So you need to access the nested array first and then the hash.

Comment: Huh?  How did it become nested?  And what incantation is required to unnest it?   [0] does not help.  And what exactly are $%@..  They are sort of just syntactic noise, but also sort of operators that change semantics.  I call them "perls".  Thanks, but

Comment: It becomes nested here : `my @cols = $tables{"grp"};` Basically you create a new array and inside of it you add your array from the %tables hash. You can see it with: `print "Inside tables", Dumper($tables{"grp"}),"\n";` now there is only a single array with hashes now.

Comment: You can unnest it by doing: `my @arr = map {$_->[0]} @cols;

print Dumper(\@arr);` This will print the first element of the array which is the array that you want.

Answer (score 1):

Following sample demo code provides one of many possible ways to form what OP named as database *shema*.

OP in function `addColumn($name, $type)` does not specifies what table the column belong to.

It would be nice to see what final data structure OP expects to *build* to clarify what would be final result.

The sample code provided in a hope that it might assist OP in finding solution to his/her problem.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my %tables;

tbAddColumn('grp','id','serial');
tbAddColumn('grp','part','integer');

tbAddColumn('tab2','foo2','varchar');
tbAddColumn('tab2','bar2','integer');

say Dumper(\%tables);

my $tb_name = 'grp';

say "Table: $tb_name";
say '-' x 45;

for my $column ( @{$tables{$tb_name}{columns}} ) {
    say "name => $column->{name}, type => $column->{type}";
}

exit 0;

sub tbAddColumn {
    my $tbname = shift;
    my $name   = shift;
    my $type   = shift;

    push @{$tables{$tbname}{columns}}, { name => $name, type => $type};
}
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = {
          'tab2' => {
                      'columns' => [
                                     {
                                       'name' => 'foo2',
                                       'type' => 'varchar'
                                     },
                                     {
                                       'name' => 'bar2',
                                       'type' => 'integer'
                                     }
                                   ]
                    },
          'grp' => {
                     'columns' => [
                                    {
                                      'name' => 'id',
                                      'type' => 'serial'
                                    },
                                    {
                                      'type' => 'integer',
                                      'name' => 'part'
                                    }
                                  ]
                   }
        };

Table: grp
---------------------------------------------
name => id, type => serial
name => part, type => integer
```

NOTE: OP could do some reading on [object oriented programming](https://www.perltutorial.org/perl-oop/) in Perl which would allow incapsulate table data/structure into an object. Result code would look much cleaner and easier to maintain.

Sample of pseudo code

```
......
my $tb1 = new dbTable('grp');
my $tb2 = new dbTable('tab2');

$tb1->addColumn('id','serial');
$tb1->addColumn('part','integer');


$tb2->addColumn('foo2','varchar');
$tb2->addColumn('bar2','integer');
.....
```

Comment: OP used a global variable to store the current table ($columns) to make the calls a bit more succinct, and it seems to produce the correct structure according to Dumper.  Could have used a different style.  But you do not address my question, namely how do I index into the created structure.  (I also do not understand your fancy push, but that is not the question.)

Comment: You address into the structure as follows `$tables{$tbname}{columns}[$index]{$key}` (or you could use `$tables{'grp'}{'columns'}[0]{'name'}` for example, if a _key_ consist of one word then quotation marks can be omitted). `$tables{$tbname}{columns}` is an _arrayref_, you can not _push_ element into _arrayref_, it requires to be dereferenced `@{$arrayref}`.

Comment: @Tuntable 
I have edited your question with addendum demonstrating an access to stored data, though creating a copy of an array/hash per your code sample (unnecessary in this particular case as copy takes memory and CPU cycles). If you do not need duplicate data then access can be achieved through reference to an array/hash -- it much faster, do not consume memory and saves CPU cycles .

Comment: @PolarBear I've rolled back your edit on the question. The code you added came with no explanations, and the text belonged in an answer rather than in the question. Remember that you can post multiple answers if you want to.

Comment: @Dada - it if fine with me, I do not care about this question any more.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `%cols[1]` is an [index-value array slice](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata#Slices). If `@cols` only has a single element, the value at index 1 is undefined and `%cols[1]` returns the list `(1, undef)` which is assigned to `%col` at line 4 in your first snippet:

```
my %col = %cols[1];
```

So now `%col = ("1" => undef)` and when you try to print it on line 5:

```
print "COLvar ", %col, " ", "\n";
```

It tries to print the key "1" joined with the value `undef` which gives a warning and then the output:

```
Use of uninitialized value in print
COLvar 1
```

Comment: Huh?  $cols[1] does not work.  So how does one not do a slice and do a simple index?

Comment: @Tuntable In this case `$#cols == 0` so `$cols[1]` does not exist. I am not sure what you mean by *"does not work"*. Please clarify